# What causes Dask futures to get stuck in 'pending' state?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-kubernetes

I created my own very slightly modified `Dockerfile` based on [the `dask-docker` `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/dask/dask-docker/blob/master/base/Dockerfile) that installs `adlfs` and copies one of my custom libraries into the container in order to make it available to all worker nodes. I deployed my container to my Kubernetes cluster and have connected to it from a REPL on my local machine, creating a client and a function locally:

```py
>>> def add1(n): return n + 1
...
>>> client = Client(my_ip + ':8786')
```

But when I run `client.submit`, I'm getting either `distributed.protocol.pickle` "Failed to deserialize b'...'" error messages or Futures stuck in a 'pending' state:

```py
>>> f = client.submit(add1, 2)
>>> distributed.protocol.pickle - INFO - Failed to deserialize b'\x80\x05\x95\xba\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x16tblib.pickling_support...'
...
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5
>>>
>>> f = client.submit(add1, 2)
>>> f
<Future: pending, key: add1-d5d2ff94399d4bb4e41150868f4c6da7>
```

It seems like the pickle protocol error will occur only once when I submit the first job, then afterward, everything is just stuck in `pending`.

From `kubectl`, I see that I have:

- one `LoadBalancer` service named `dask-scheduler`,
- two deployments: 1x `dask-scheduler` and 3x `dask-worker`,
- and the corresponding one `dask-scheduler-...` and three `dask-worker-...` pods

What would cause this, and how can I debug? I opened up the web interface to my Dask scheduler, and it shows that I have an instance of `add1` that has erred, but it gives no details.

For what it's worth, the only changes I made to the `Dockerfile` were:

```
    # ...
    && find /opt/conda/lib/python*/site-packages/bokeh/server/static -type f,l -name '*.js' -not -name '*.min.js' -delete \
    && rm -rf /opt/conda/pkgs

RUN pip install adlfs==0.3.0          # new line

COPY prepare.sh /usr/bin/prepare.sh   # existing line
COPY foobar.sh /usr/bin/foobar.sh     # new line
COPY my_file.so /usr/bin/my_file.so   # new line
```

*Edit*: I'll note that if I deploy the Dask image (`image: "daskdev/dask:2.11.0"` in my K8s manifest), things work just fine. So in trying to create a customized Docker image, something seems to get misconfigured with Dask. I commented out my changes to the `Dockerfile`, ran `docker rmi` on my local and [ACR](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-registry/) images, tore down my deployed service and deployments, then rebuilt a container, pushed it, and made the deployment, but it *still* fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is the distinction between the Dask image I was successfully deploying and the `Dockerfile` upon which I was creating my own image. The former (2.11.0), [bakes in Dask 2.11.0](https://github.com/dask/dask-docker/blob/a26a0a546c954a981e6777541ee70f01149ac207/base/Dockerfile#L7) while the latter [bakes in both Dask 2.16.0 and Python 3.8](https://github.com/dask/dask-docker/blob/82a77468f3294661eb5228ace964f147b6a2c517/base/Dockerfile). Some difference in these versions causes the issue.

When I update my `Dockerfile` to use 2.11.0 and remove the explicit Python dependency, things work fine.